# SSRS 2012 Inscope for row + column group to calculate difference

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to perform that calculation in rdl directly to get that difference which comes from row + column group column?

Please refer to my previous post for sample data if needed. [Previous post details click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575046/ssrs-2012-display-only-group-totals-in-tablix)

I'd like to compute that value in F2,3,4 column.
Thanks for all help.
M

[image: details picture is here]

This is selfcontained rdl, just put your server name.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Tablix Name="Tablix1">
        <TablixCorner>
          <TablixCornerRows>
            <TablixCornerRow>
              <TablixCornerCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="Textbox4">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>Region</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>Textbox4</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <BackgroundColor>LimeGreen</BackgroundColor>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCornerCell>
            </TablixCornerRow>
          </TablixCornerRows>
        </TablixCorner>
        <TablixBody>
          <TablixColumns>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>1in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>1in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>1in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
          </TablixColumns>
          <TablixRows>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox3">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=count("1")</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox3</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <LeftBorder>
                          <Color>Black</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                          <Width>1pt</Width>
                        </LeftBorder>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox6">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=count("1")/count("1","YEAR")</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <Format>0.00%</Format>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox6</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <RightBorder>
                          <Color>Black</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                          <Width>1pt</Width>
                        </RightBorder>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox14">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=IIF(count("1") = 3,"40-14=26%","?")</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox14</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <BackgroundColor>Yellow</BackgroundColor>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox8">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=count("1")</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox8</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <TopBorder>
                          <Color>Black</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                          <Width>1pt</Width>
                        </TopBorder>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox9">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox9</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <TopBorder>
                          <Color>Black</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                          <Width>1pt</Width>
                        </TopBorder>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox15">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox15</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <TopBorder>
                          <Color>Black</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                          <Width>1pt</Width>
                        </TopBorder>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
          </TablixRows>
        </TablixBody>
        <TablixColumnHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember>
              <Group Name="YEAR">
                <GroupExpressions>
                  <GroupExpression>=Fields!YEAR.Value</GroupExpression>
                </GroupExpressions>
              </Group>
              <TablixHeader>
                <Size>0.25in</Size>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="Textbox2">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>=Fields!YEAR.Value</Value>
                            <Style>
                              <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                            </Style>
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style>
                          <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                        </Style>
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>Textbox2</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <BackgroundColor>LimeGreen</BackgroundColor>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixHeader>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember />
                <TablixMember />
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember>
              <TablixHeader>
                <Size>0.25in</Size>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="Textbox13">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>Difference</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style>
                          <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                        </Style>
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>Textbox13</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <BackgroundColor>Yellow</BackgroundColor>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixHeader>
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixColumnHierarchy>
        <TablixRowHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember>
              <Group Name="Region">
                <GroupExpressions>
                  <GroupExpression>=Fields!Region.Value</GroupExpression>
                </GroupExpressions>
              </Group>
              <SortExpressions>
                <SortExpression>
                  <Value>=Fields!Region.Value</Value>
                </SortExpression>
              </SortExpressions>
              <TablixHeader>
                <Size>1in</Size>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="Region">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>=Fields!Region.Value</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>Region</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <RightBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </RightBorder>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixHeader>
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember>
              <TablixHeader>
                <Size>1in</Size>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="Textbox7">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>Total</Value>
                            <Style>
                              <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                            </Style>
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>Textbox7</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <TopBorder>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                        <Width>1pt</Width>
                      </TopBorder>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixHeader>
              <KeepWithGroup>Before</KeepWithGroup>
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixRowHierarchy>
        <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
        <Height>0.75in</Height>
        <Width>4in</Width>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
        </Style>
      </Tablix>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>0.76042in</Height>
    <Style />
  </Body>
  <Width>4in</Width>
  <Page>
    <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
    <Style />
  </Page>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>Data Source=dwvm;Initial Catalog=master</ConnectString>
        <IntegratedSecurity>true</IntegratedSecurity>
      </ConnectionProperties>
      <rd:SecurityType>Integrated</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>02a410c1-7691-4044-b48e-1c2cfd1ac685</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>WITH cte AS (SELECT        'Asia' AS Region, 2012 AS YEAR, 'Wo' AS Cust
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT        'Asia' AS Region, 2012 AS YEAR, 'Ma' AS Cust
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT        'Asia' AS Region, 2013 AS YEAR, 'Li' AS Cust
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT        'Asia' AS Region, 2013 AS YEAR, 'Xo' AS Cust
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT        'Asia' AS Region, 2013 AS YEAR, 'Xo' AS Cust
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT        'Africa' AS Region, 2012 AS YEAR, 'Cora' AS Cust
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT        'Africa' AS Region, 2012 AS YEAR, 'Lamy' AS Cust
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT        'Africa' AS Region, 2013 AS YEAR, 'Kary' AS Cust
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT        'US' AS Region, 2013 AS YEAR, 'Michael' AS Cust
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT        'US' AS Region, 2013 AS YEAR, 'Rachelle' AS Cust
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT        'US' AS Region, 2013 AS YEAR, 'Rafael' AS Cust
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT        'US' AS Region, 2013 AS YEAR, 'Minace' AS Cust
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT        'US' AS Region, 2012 AS YEAR, 'Landley' AS Cust)
    SELECT        Region, YEAR, Cust
     FROM            cte AS cte_1</CommandText>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="Region">
          <DataField>Region</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="YEAR">
          <DataField>YEAR</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Cust">
          <DataField>Cust</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>3d834541-c3dc-4dd5-86f6-007dea45a763</rd:ReportID>

    </Report>
```

Comment: Have you already tried `=Count(Fields!Cust.Value) - Count(Fields!Cust.Value)/Count(Fields!Cust.Value, "YEAR")`?

Comment: Thanks Steven, You mean to use in F2,3,4 cell? Those 2 expressions you noted used in the same column group, I think they will produce not correct result. I need calc outside of column group, big challenge is that I need to refer to 2 instances of column group YEAR separately.

Comment: I need to refer to highlighted cells  like on pic (50% and 20%) but outside of column group,I will attach test rdl today for testing. Tx again.M

Comment: I found some simular example in [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2009/08/11/tablix-multiple-subtotals-are-easy-aka-goodbye-inscope/)

Comment: I don't think It's possible or at least feasible, I think I'm going to prepare this in my sql. Tx